# How to calculate variables which are in different lines (tr) of table in js?

Tags: html, jquery

Variables in below codes of js are

> a= first column of table
> b= second column
> c= third column
> d= forth column

```
$(document).on('keyup','input.expenses',function(){
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
       // collect the 3 inputs in this row only
       $exp = $row.find('.expenses'),
       a = $exp.eq(0).val(),// first is a
       b = $exp.eq(1).val(),// second is b
       c = $exp.eq(2).val(),// third is c
       d = $exp.eq(3).val();// fourth is d
   var total = (a*c - b*c)-d;
   $row.find("#toplamdisplay").val(total); 
})
```

As it seems all variables will be calculated in the same line (same tr)

How can I use variable d (field of d) which is located in other line ?
For example

Current tags are

```
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
</tr>
```

New tags I want to use are something like this

```
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>d</td>
</tr>
```

What I want is to have one payment field in last  instead of having it in column. Please see below tags

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" /></script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<script>
$(document).on('keyup','input.expenses',function(){
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
       // collect the 3 inputs in this row only
       $exp = $row.find('.expenses'),
       a = $exp.eq(0).val(),// first is a
       b = $exp.eq(1).val(),// second is b
       c = $exp.eq(2).val(),// third is c
       d = $exp.eq(3).val();// fourth is d
       //(B TIMES C)-(A TIMES C)
   var total = (a*c - b*c)-d;
   $row.find("#toplamdisplay").val(total);
   $row.find('.expenses_sum').text( total)   
})




$(document).on('keyup','input.expenses',function(){
  $expenses_sum = $(this).parents('table').find('.expenses_sum');
  $expenseTotal = $(this).parents('table').find('#expenses_sum2');
  $expenseTotal.val('0');
  $.each($expenses_sum,function(index,object){      
    if($(object).val()!='')
    {
 $expenseTotal.val(parseInt($expenseTotal.val())+parseInt($(object).val()));
    }
  })  
});




$(document).on('keyup','input.expenses',function(){
  $expenses_sum = $(this).parents('table').find('.expenses_sum2');
  $expenseTotal = $(this).parents('table').find('#expenses_sum3');
  $expenseTotal.val('0');
  $.each($expenses_sum,function(index,object){      
    if($(object).val()!='')
    {
 $expenseTotal.val(parseInt($expenseTotal.val())+parseInt($(object).val()));
    }
  })  
});


</script>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Quantity Returned</th>
<th>Unit Price</th>
<th>Total Price</th>
<th bgcolor="red">Payment</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="number" name="" class="expenses Quantity" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="" data-diff="true"  class="expenses QuantityBack" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="" class="expenses title UnitPrice" value="150" /></td>
<td><span class="toplamc"></span></td>
<td bgcolor="red"><input type="number" name="" data-diff="true"  class="expenses paid" />
<input type="number" hidden name="" readonly id="toplamdisplay" class="expenses_sum" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><input type="number" name="" class="expenses Quantity" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="" data-diff="true"  class="expenses QuantityBack" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="" class="expenses title UnitPrice" value="200" /></td>
<td><span class="toplamc"></span></td>
<td bgcolor="red"><input type="number" name="" data-diff="true"  class="expenses paid" />
<input type="number" hidden name="" readonly id="toplamdisplay" class="expenses_sum" /></td>
</tr>

      
      
      
  <tr>
      <td rowspan="3"></td>
      <td rowspan="3"></td>
      <td>Current Value</td> 
      <td><input type="number" readonly id="expenses_sum2"  class="expenses_sum2" /></td> 
      <td rowspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Last Value</td> 
      <td><input type="number" readonly class="expenses_sum2" name="" value="66" /></td>      
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
      <td><b>Total</b></td> 
      <td><input type="number" name="TotalCredit" readonly id="expenses_sum3"></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3"></td>
  <td><font color="red">I NEED FIELD OF PAYMENT TO BE HERE</font></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please anyone can help me to edit js to work with my second logic of tags

Comment: You can try like this ---> `$row.next('tr').find('inputbox_class').val()`

Comment: [jQuery next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: it's not working

Comment: @Schadro show your table structure with demo datas .

Comment: Hello Swati, I edited my tags. Please see the demo as you requested. thank you

Comment: what doesn't work currently ? didn't understood your current edit ? can you elaborate

Comment: All works fine, but what I need to change is to put field of payment in last <TR> or in first <TR> before <TH>. When I replace that payment field to last or first <TR> calculation stops to work to Current Value and Total fields. Please anyone can help me

Comment: Sorry can you tell me how these values should be calculated ? How total should happen also where is d variable value taken from ? Also check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/c8y3gLhf/1/) .Let me know what is wrong in this .

Comment: a=Quantity; b=Quantity Returned; c=Unit Price; d=Payment field (in your fiddle it is total price). Current Value= (a*c)-(b*c); Last Value= Value from DB or static value no problem;  Total=(Current Value+Last Value)-Payment Field.  BUT PAYMENT FIELD I NEED IT TO BE IN THE FIELD WHICH HAS RED COLOR IN YOUR fiddle. thank you

Comment: Hi check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/ap8Ly1rs/1/) corrected values .

Comment: Thank you so much Swat, it works. the remaining thing is to auto calculate Total even while typing in Quantity fields

Comment: @Schadro its auto calculating `total` and `current` values already .

Comment: Yes, Total will be auto calculated only when we have default value in payment field, please check. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220507/discussion-between-swati-and-schadro).